# ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor Not Selecting Prepoulated Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

First of all, I have checked all the related questions but none of them solves my problem.

I am using ASP.NET MVC Html helper Dropdownlistfor with multiple property as follows.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPeople, 
                       Model.People, 
                       new { multiple = "multiple" })

/* Viewmodel for my view */
public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> People       { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedPeople       { get; set; }
}
```

If i do not prepopulate the dropdownlist with some selected values. It works fine. Selected values are posted to action method without no problems.

However, if I want to prepopulate the dropdownlist, it is not working. I populate the dropdownlist as follows,

```
model.People = new[] 
{
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "group 1" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "group 2" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "group 3" },
 };

model.SelectedPeople = new[] { "2", "3" };
```

By not working, I mean SelectListItems 2 and 3 are not selected in DropDownList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
model.People = new[] 
{
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "group 1" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "group 2", Selected = true },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "group 3", Selected = true },
};
```

Comment: this works, any ideas what is wrong with my approach ? Thanks.